# How to combine lapply, t.test, leveneTest, if and else

Tags: r, lapply, t-test

I want to create a list of t-test results, where the appropriate corrections for unequal variances have been applied, if a levene-test indicated that they were necessary. Here are some example data.

```
#create dataset
set.seed(555)
data<- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:2], each = 5),
                  var1 = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 1.2, sd = 1),
                  var2 = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 2.8, sd = .50))

>data
   group       var1     var2
1      a 1.89686907 2.696915
2      a 1.66000554 2.650026
3      a 0.03941319 2.932389
4      a 2.47693939 2.674999
5      a 0.14176879 2.650867
6      b 1.24219445 2.889152
7      b 1.87350165 2.576014
8      b 1.10712963 3.082120
9      b 1.00297421 2.502752
10     b 2.64126704 2.314156
>
```

I found out how to create lists of levene-test results and t-test results (in this example, I assume equal variances for all t-tests).

```
levene.tests<-lapply(data[,c("var1","var2")],
                     function(x) leveneTest(x ~ data$group))
t.tests<-lapply(data[,c("var1","var2")],
                function(x) t.test(x ~ data$group, var.equal = TRUE))
```

And I also managed to use if and else, so R will choose the right type of test for me based on whether variances are equal or not for *single* variables.

```
#if else statement for var1 only
if (levene.tests$"var1"$"Pr(>F)"[1]<.05) {
  t.test(data$var1 ~ data$group, var.equal = FALSE)
} else {
  t.test(data$var1 ~ data$group, var.equal = TRUE)
}
```

What I am struggling with now is how to piece these codes together, so that I get the appropriate t-test result for all variables (in this case var1 and var2) in a list type object. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one option where we loop over the `names` of 'levene.tests', extract the 'p.value', check if it is greater than or equal to 0.05 and use that logical value in 'var.equal of `t.test`

```
library(car)
out <- lapply(names(levene.tests), function(nm) {
    i1 <- levene.tests[[nm]]$"Pr(>F)"[1] >= 0.05
    t.test(data[[nm]]~ data$group, var.equal = i1)
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found that might help, using `sapply` function to the levene test you conducted (extracting "Pr(>F)" of the `leveneTest`):

```
levene.r <- sapply(levene.tests, `[`, c("Pr(>F)"))

levene.r
```

if needed, transpose `levene.r`

```
t(levene.r)
```

It should also work for the ttest (just need to look on str to extract the things you want form this object).